# Azure service bus queue AutoLockRenewer seems to be failing to renew the lock

Tags: python, azure, queue, azureservicebus

I am running a python code which listens to an azure servicebus queue

The actual processing of a message can be sometimes long (~10 minutes or more)

The lock duration on the queue settings is 3.5 minutes (was already 5 but reduced by recommendation in this thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/11983)

Looks like it doesnt matter what value I am using for the max duration parameter, I still get the following error:

> azure.servicebus.exceptions.ServiceBusError: The lock on the message
> lock has expired on self.complete_message(msg)

```
try:
    self.init_servicebus()

    with AutoLockRenewer() as renewer:

        with self.servicebus_client:
            self.init_receiver()
            with self.receiver:
                received_msgs = self.receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=1, max_wait_time=5)
                data_logger.warning(f"Received {len(received_msgs)} messages from the queue")

                for msg in received_msgs:
                    try:

                        renewer.register(self.receiver, msg, max_lock_renewal_duration=1200)
                        data_logger.info("Register messages into AutoLockRenewer done.")

                        msg: azure.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage
                        data_logger.info(f"Message {msg.message_id} received")

                        stat = self.process_message(msg)
                        if stat == -1:
                            # todo: need to decide what to do with failed messages
                            # it means that a file could not be parsed for some reason
                            pass

                        else:
                            self.complete_message(msg)

                            data_logger.info(f"Message {msg.message_id} completed")

                    except Exception as e:
                        data_logger.error(
                            f"Message processing failed. Exception of type {e.__class__} occurred. Error: {str(e)} \n"
                            f"Traceback: {traceback.format_exc()}")

                        self.requeue_process_message(msg)

                        data_logger.info(f"Message {msg.message_id} requeued")

except Exception as e:
    data_logger.error(
        f"Method poll_messages failed. Exception of type {e.__class__} occurred. Error: {str(e)} \n"
        f"Traceback: {traceback.format_exc()}")
```

Comment: [Session Lock Expired with AutoLockRenew when message takes 4-5mn of processing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/14699), [False lock expiration error when receiving very large messages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/16934) and [When receiving messages of large size that require long period processing, the locks of future incoming messages are expired](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/16703)

Comment: The issues that @DeepDave-MT has mentioned have since been fixed (after version 7.1.1). Can you add the `azure-servicebus` and `uamqp` versions that you are using?